# Serializing Dates with Protocol Buffers

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

So after some searching, its been suggested to use an `int64` epoch.

This is all well and great, but when interacting with my model, I would like to interact with actual `LocalDate` objects, so what are strategies for handling this?

The two strategies I can think of are:

- transform the deserialized model into ANOTHER different model. This is creating an extra object, I was hoping to avoid this.
- edit the generated models. I can't find any documentation on this so its probably quite risky

What is the common practice here?

Comment: Editing the generated code is a bad idea. It makes maintenance difficult. Years and years down the road when you're gone, somebody will curse you for doing that.

Comment: So is the common practice to create another model?

Comment: In my experience, yes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I went with creating a generic solution for all dates/times:

```
message Timestamp {
    int64 seconds = 1;
    int32 nanos = 2;
}
```

With the following converters:

```
public static Timestamp fromLocalDate(LocalDate localDate) {
    Instant instant = localDate.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    return Timestamp.newBuilder()
        .setSeconds(instant.getEpochSecond())
        .setNanos(instant.getNano())
        .build();
}

public static LocalDate toLocalDate(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(timestamp.getSeconds(), timestamp.getNanos()), ZoneId.of("UTC"))
        .toLocalDate();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to create your own version of Timestamp.

You can simply use `google.protobuf.Timestamp` ([source](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto)):

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
message Application {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp date = 1;
}
```

It's the standard (proto) way to create `Date` objects.

It's easy to convert an `Instant` into a `google.Timestamp` with the new Java8 time API

```
LocalDate date = ...;
final Instant instant = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(date.atStartOfDay()).toInstant();        
Timestamp t = Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds(instant.getEpochSecond()).build();
```

Please note that Google protobuf lib contains an helper for `Timestamp`:

https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/Timestamps.java

Answer (score 1):

You should never edit the generated code. Among many reasons this is a bad idea, your edited code may not work with future versions of the Protobuf library.

Generally, converting from `int64` to some sort of `Date` object is cheap. I'd suggest leaving the data in `int64` format and only constructing a `LocalDate` object on-demand when you need it.

That said, it is also common practice to maintain a separate, hand-written model, and only use the Protobuf classes at parse / serialize time.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of editing the class definition as such, but just adding an interface to class it generates which has a default method on it to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The generated properties in the C# class aren't the .NET date and time types. The properties use the `Timestamp` and `Duration` classes in the `Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes` namespace. These classes provide methods for converting to and from `DateTimeOffset`, `DateTime`, and `TimeSpan`.

```
   syntax = "proto3"
  
   import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message Meeting {
    string subject = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp time = 2;
}
```